# can i run magento2 on top of a mysql5.0 version?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-1.7, database

Am i able to run and build **magento2** on top of a **mysql 5.0** stack without downgrading the version of magento2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean MySQL 5.0 specifically, or MYSQL 5 in general?

Magento 2 requires MySQL 5.6 or 5.7. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

I don't think it's possible to run even Magento 1 on MySQL 5.0. That's a very old version. Current docs say MySQL 5.6 is required (although, from experience, 5.5 should work too). http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html